# Iterating over a subset of Apps in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-apps

As part of a Django project, my user will be able to select from a variety of options. The functionality for each option is stored in a separate app. My project structure looks something like this:

```
MyProject/
    MyProject
    App1
    App2
    Options/
        Option1/
        Option2/
        Option3/
        …
    …
    manage.py
```

Option1, Option2 etc. is each an App in its own right, and listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` My question is: Is there a way of iterating over each app contained within the options directory. For example suppose each app contained a file called utils.py with a function called foo in each utils.py.

Is there a way of doing something like this:

```
from .. import Options
survey = [ app.utils.foo() for app in Options]
```

Failing this, is there a way to just iterate over all apps? Is there something I can do with `django.apps` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you've configures your apps.py

```
from django.apps import apps

for name, app in apps.app_configs.items():
    if name in ['OPTIONS-N']:
        utils = app.module.utils
```

Comment: Hi tobey, that's really helpful thanks. I can't quite get the ['OPTIONS-N'] bit to work, is that just your shorthand for a list of all the apps that are contained within the options directory? or is there some syntax I'm unfamiliar with?

Comment: also, this gives me the error: module 'Options.Option1' has no attribute 'utils'. If I include from .options1 import utils, it will work okay, but then I will need that line for each app, which kind of defeats the point of the code in the first place, because I would like it to be dynamic.

Comment: yes, "Option-N" was shorthand for a list of options. Make sure all your "Option-N" folders contain an `__init__.py`. You may need to add the line `from . import utils` there

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Python packages don't automatically import their modules / sub-packages. Thanks